# CodeIgniter form call to undefined function form_dropdown() error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create 2 *dropdown* list. First of them includes main categories, second one includes subcategories.

In codeigniter view i have this lines:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Top Level Option</label></td>
        <td><?php echo form_dropdown('options', $options, '#', 'id="options"'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Sub Level Option</label></td>
        <td><select name="suboptions" id="suboptions"><option value="#">-- Please Select Sub-option --</option></select></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But i have an error in echo `form_dropdown()` line:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `form_dropdown()`.

How can I use this `form_dropdown()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the **[form helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)** file at first.

Whether to use `$this->load->helper('form')` within the **Controller** *(in which you load the view file)*

Or to load the helper automatically by adding the name of the helper to `$autoload` array config:

**application\config\autoload.php**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form');
```